# Problem with smarty replace ans ISO-8859-1 on php 7.2 and German Umlauts

Tags: php, replace, smarty, iso-8859-1, php-7.2

I've got a replace function in my template, nothing special.

```
{$description:replace:'http://www.youtube':'https://www.youtube'}
```

$description can contains German Umlauts and ISO-8859-1 characters. On php < 7.1 it works. When i switch to php 7.1 or 7.2 and $description contains Umlauts the function outputs nothing (just nothing).

The same happens with that function which works on php < 7.1:

```
{assign var="title" value=mb_convert_encoding($item->title, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8")}
{$title|replace:" ? ":" - "}
```

Why does smarty has problems with replace string with Umlauts and ISO-8859-1 charas on php higher than 7.0?

Comment: What smarty version are you using? Also try to assign the variable title in .php and then assign it to your template file and see what happens

Comment: I'm using 3.1.31.
Okay, i'll try that.

Comment: @Aaron When i assign the variable in php it works. But where's the problem now?

Comment: I'm not too much of an smarty expert and how it calls the php functions. Technically there shouldn't be a problem. Can you try to just print the variable title and dont use the replace function? I think there is a problem with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is not technically an answer, but I need more features than a comment supports.

One way to debug issues like this one is by inserting debug messages in the library code. I would start at [modifier.replace.php](https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/blob/master/libs/plugins/modifier.replace.php), which makes the decision to call Smarty's own [mb_str_replace](https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/blob/master/libs/plugins/shared.mb_str_replace.php) or the native, non-multibyte-safe `str_replace`. The decision is based on the existence of the function [mb_get_info](https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/blob/master/libs/Smarty.class.php#L62), which I assume boils down to whether you have mbstring support compiled into PHP (I'm pretty sure you do).

Further, I would look at the [basecase](https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/blob/master/libs/plugins/shared.mb_str_replace.php#L47) in `mb_str_replace` to see what arguments it receives and what it returns.

Good luck!